# Twitter Bootstrap 3 : Firefox misalignment grid model multi lines in a single row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've got strange problem of alignement when i m cascading multi lines

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

under FIREFOX i get a strange misalignment, any idea why ?

sample : 
http://bb.dev2.oscim.net/module_sport/

thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap support 12 column row. So you should keep total of 12 columns in one row.
Like this ...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hum ... it work on any browser with more than 12 column, thanks for suggestion.
See doc here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping